# DevTools Protocol - Whats the difference between Target.getTargets and requesting the /json endpoint?

Tags: google-chrome-devtools, google-chrome-headless

According to the [Chrome DevTools protocol viewer page](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/):

> In this scenario, you can substitute Developer Tools front-end with your own implementation. Instead of navigating to the HTML page at http://localhost:9222, your application can discover available pages by requesting: http://localhost:9222/json and getting a JSON object with information about inspectable pages along with the WebSocket addresses that you could use in order to start instrumenting them.

However, [according to the the Target Domain documentation](https://chromedevtools.github.io/devtools-protocol/tot/Target/), sending a message (**via websockets**) with `{"method": "Target.getTargets"}` returns a "list of available targets":

> Target.getTargets
>   #
>   Retrieves a list of available targets.
>
> RETURN OBJECT:
>
> `targetInfos`
>   `array` `[ TargetInfo ]`:
>   The list of targets.

What is the difference?

Comment: Is there any difference in the actual output? If there's none then these are simply different methods to get the same information, obviously.

Comment: There is difference in the output. Thanks for pointing this out; my question is really "what does the /Json endpoint response data represent?"

Answer (score 0):

Per aslushnikov's answer on the GH issue:

> The `Target` domain is a modern and recommended way to explore targets. It also allows to communicate with multiple targets only a single connection.

Followed by:

> The `/json` endpoint is an old way to explore and connect to targets.

Essentially, both seem to be fine; however, my take away is that using the `Target.getTargets` method is newly preferred